# How to increment a number but keep formatting

Tags: c#, xml

I have a small XML that I read in in order to get the test id. I need to increment that number but keep the same formatting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Test>
   <TestID>00001</TestID>  
</Test>
```

```
testID = xDoc.Descendants("TestID").First().Value;
```

If I just convert testID to int it becomes 0. I need the output to be `00002` after increment and then I need to write it back to the XML file.

Comment: So, format your int with leading spaces up to 5 digits? See [the "0" specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#Specifier0)

Comment: @canton7 But when I convert it from string to int in order to increment the number I lose those last 4 numbers.

Comment: Right, and when you convert from your incremented int back to a string, you can add them back on again!

Comment: testID = xDoc.Descendants("TestID").First().Value.ToString("0000");  You probably want XElement id =  xDoc.Descendants("TestID").First();  id.SetValue("string");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var testIdElement = xDoc.Root.Element("TestID");
testIdElement.Value = ((int)testIdElement + 1).ToString("D5");
```

We convert the value of "TestID" to an int, increment it, then format it as a string with 5 digits, padded with leading zeros.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `XmlDocument`

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
var testId = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Test/TestID");
testId.InnerText = (Convert.ToInt32(testId.InnerText)+1).ToString("D5");
xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
```