# How to determine the format of an integer , increment it , and return it in the same format based on the input?

Tags: c#, string, integer, format

My question is similar to this question **[How to increment a number but keep formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301100/how-to-increment-a-number-but-keep-formatting)** except the format is not known beforehand and is determined by the input integer.

So if I enter 0001, it will return 0002, if I enter 01, it will return 02, if I enter 1, it will return 2.

I know for known formats like 0001 I can convert it ToString("000"), but I don't know how to get the format of the any input integer and apply it back after the increment.

Comment: What is your code? Your tries? Your research? There is plenty of answers here to read about this.

Comment: Integers don't have a format. You are talking about strings. It seems to me that your question amounts to "how do I determine how many characters there are in a string". You don't need our help to answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are working with strings which can be incremented using the following method.

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static string NextValue(string sender)
    {
        string value = Regex.Match(sender, "[0-9]+$").Value;
        return sender[..^value.Length] + (long.Parse(value) + 1)
            .ToString().PadLeft(value.Length, '0');
    }
}
```

Sample usage

```
string[] values = new[] {"0001", "01", "A001" };

foreach (var value in values)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{value,-10}{Helpers.NextValue(value)}");
}
```

Results

```
0001      0002
01        02
A001      A002
```